# Creating Azure Run As account for automation

Tags: azure

I am trying out the `Azure` automation feature and I encountered the error below when the system tried to create the Run As account:

> An error occurred while creating the Azure Run As account (service principal) for account `automateTest2`.
>
> Error details:
> {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}.

I am still quite new to Azure and my subscription is a free trial one.

Appreciate your assistance on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The user performing these steps must be a member of the Subscription Admins role and co-administrator of the subscription which is granting access to the subscription for the user. The user must also be added as a User to that subscriptions default Active Directory; the account does not need to be assigned to a privileged role.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-sec-configure-azure-runas-account

Comment: So just an owner of the subscription is not enough ?
I have this problem now that i am an owner of the subscription and i can't create it either !

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error is pretty obvious, you need more permission to do that, try contributor role or owner role (of your subscription) to create those.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have checked the subscription and it is shown that I have the owner role.

not sure what else I need to check