# Can not create a Run as account and I do have owner rights in the subscription

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory

I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988512/creating-azure-run-as-account-for-automation) out that you need to have owner rights of your subscription to add a Run as account in an Automation account. But as I search in my services I can see that my role inside the subscription is as an owner. Still i can't create a run as account because i don't have enough permissions ?
Is it enough to only have the owner rights of the subscriptions or do I need any more permissions ?

Comment: what your role in your aad tenant? And is the Azure AD tenant's `Users can register applications option` in `User settings` page is set to `Yes`?

Comment: I don't have access to the user settings page in the azure ad.
Can it be that my aad tenant role is guest but the subscription is owner ?

Comment: I suppose you do not have the permission to create AAD App, if so, you could not configure Run As accounts.

Comment: I will try to ask the global administrator to give me rights .
Thnx for the answer @JoyWang

Comment: I have added an answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by you do not have the permission to create the AAD App.

If you want to configure Run As accounts, you also need to have the permission to create the AAD App.

For more details about the permissions, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account#permissions).

Answer (score 1):

Except for the permissions equivalent to the Owner role for Microsoft. Automation resources, you need to check these:

In the Azure portal, under Azure Active Directory > MANAGE > App registrations, if App registrations is set to Yes, non-admin users in your Azure AD tenant can [register Active Directory applications.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#check-azure-subscription-permissions) If App registrations is set to No, the user who performs this action must be a global administrator in Azure AD.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-create-standalone-account#permissions-required-to-create-an-automation-account